# How to write multi statements in a range block with Dlang?

Tags: d

I would like to write multi statements in a range block, like this:

```
long[] W = [0L];
long[] V = [0L];

array.each!(s => // "s" has following strings "3 4" 
  W ~= s.split(" ")[0].to!long;
  V ~= s.split(" ")[1].to!long;
);
```

But this causes compile error. Is there any way to write all statements in the range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use slightly longer form function syntax:

```
long[] W = [0L];
long[] V = [0L];

array.each!( (s) {
    W ~= s.split(" ")[0].to!long;
    V ~= s.split(" ")[1].to!long;
  }
);
```

`(s) { x; y; z; }` works anywhere `s => x` works, except with `s=>x` if you need the return value, the long-form is `(s) { return x; }`.